# arrange X axis in descending order using plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I'm trying to create an interactive plot using `plotly` and having trouble ordering the X axis. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
import plotly.tools as tls
tls.set_credentials_file(username='ladeeda', api_key='ladeeda')

cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True, theme='pearl')

StudentModalityRetention[StudentModalityRetention['schoolyearsemester'] == 'Sem3']\
   .iplot(kind='bubble', x='branch', y='retention', size='active_users', text='active_users',
             xTitle='', yTitle='Retention',
             filename='cufflinks/Sem3ModalityRetention')
```

and here's the plot that is generated:

[image]

I would like to arrange the X axis in descending order or Y axis. In other words, I would like the bubble with the highest Y value to appear first and so on..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and efficient way to achieve your goal is to sort the pandas dataframe in descending order according to your requirements and then use `iplot` to plot the graph, which will give you the desired result. Here is a short example:

```
yourdataframe.sort_values(by='Y',\   #column name or index values according to which the dataframe is to be sorted
                     axis=0,         #for column sorting
                     ascending=False,  #in your case, for descending
                     inplace = True)\  #if you want to perform the operation inplace or return a new dataframe
                     .iplot(kind='bubble', x='branch', y='retention',size='active_users', text='active_users',
                     xTitle='', yTitle='Retention',
                     filename='cufflinks/Sem3ModalityRetention')
```

Hope that helps you:))

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I added `.sort_values(axis='retention',ascending=False,inplace = True)` right before the `iplot` call and I get the following error: `
TypeError: sort_values() takes at least 2 arguments (4 given)`. I don't even have 4 arguments. Would you happen to know why this is happening?

Comment: @Patthebug Extremely sorry as I forgot to mention the 'by' parameter which is necessary for the sort_values function to work. Axis will always be 0 for column sorting. You may verify the results. Apologies for inconveniences caused if any .

Comment: Turns out, only `sort_values(by='retention',ascending=False)` was needed. No apologies needed, you were of immense help. Thanks so much :).